# folder sharing between different users of windows virtual desktop

Tags: windows, azure, virtual-desktop

Is it possible to have different users of windows virtual desktop (WVD) share content through a shared folder: Ie create in windows virtual desktop the equivalent of folder sharing between local machines connected to the same network.

Comment: Well you are in a cloud, there is nothing like a "local network" as every desktop can be hosted on a different server all over the world. I would assume that Microsoft would see OneDrive as the way to go for sharing files.

Comment: Thanks @Robert. I will dig deeper and keep you posted. It might be possible to declare a VM to "host" simply a file share: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/create-host-pools-user-profile#create-a-new-virtual-machine-that-will-act-as-a-file-share

Comment: Create a blob storage and link it to each or use it as a virtual network drive attached to each.